# Colorbar for mne.viz.plot_topomap ? Python

Tags: plot, raw, mne-python

I have two question in relation to the mne topomap function for raw (not evoked) data.

1.Is there a way to add a colorbar to the topoplot ? With evoked data it is possible, but here I have raw data...
2. Is it possible to plot the sensors dot a little bigger?

Here is the code (I hope that's enough info?):

```
ch_names = mat_data['EEG']['chanlocs']['labels']
info = mne.create_info(ch_names, ch_types=['eeg']*64 , sfreq=sampling_freq)
raw = mne.io.RawArray(data, info)
raw.set_montage('standard_1005')

%matplotlib qt
mne.viz.plot_topomap(tmp_data, raw.info, cmap='Spectral_r',sensors = True,vmin=16, vmax=26)
```

I would be ok to use a different function for the topomap if you think there is a better way to plot the topomap :)

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to this question:
https://mne.discourse.group/t/mne-viz-plot-topomap-and-color-bar/3141/4